# how to get the indices of values by the quantile?

Tags: r, list, vector, quantile

For example if my data looks like this:

```
> a <- c(1:25)
> a
[1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25
```

How do i get a list like this:

```
1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 2 3 3 3 3 3 4 4 4 4 4 5 5 5 5 5
```

**So I want to divide the 25 elements in to 5 sublists, and find out the index of the sublist that each element belongs to. Data is not sorted and is too large to sort. There are also missing values, in which case their index would be 0.**

**Sorry, to clarify, I dont need the groups to have equal sizes, but they need to be divided by the 0.2, 0.4, 0.6, 0.8 quantiles.**

i.e. the ith element in my output should be the nth quantile that the ith element in a belongs to. For example, 8 is in the second quantile, the 8th element in my output is 2.

Comment: Use `findInterval` along with `quantile` perhaps?

Comment: I don't think you can make it without first sorting your data

Comment: In response to your n-th edit: if you want to divide by the 0.2, 0.4, etc quantiles, then you do want groups of equal size, by definition.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps:

```
 acut <- cut(a, 
             quantile(a, probs=c(0, 0.2, 0.4, 0.6, 0.8, 1) ) , 
             include.lowest=TRUE)

 as.numeric(acut)
```

Comment: You could also bung `,labels=1:5` at the end of the `cut(...)` to avoid having to `as.numeric` the result.

Comment: Well, they might look like numbers but they would be factors and who know what devilment that might cause.

Answer (score 1):

```
# random data with 3 NAs
> a<-sample(c(NA,NA,NA,sample(1:1000,25)))
> a
 [1] 414 744 897 777  20 371 625 462 341 766  NA 243  NA 213 198 691  NA 325 275 526 830 179  40 601  51 725  68 709
> b<-ceiling(rank(a,na.last="keep")/length(which(!is.na(a)))*5)
> b[is.na(b)]=0
> b
 [1]  3  5  5  5  1  3  4  3  3  5 NA  2 NA  2  2  4 NA  2  2  3  5  1  1  4  1  4  1  4
# check that all groups have the same size
> table(b)
b
1 2 3 4 5 
5 5 5 5 5
```